# Name for Monge-Kantorovich transportation problem variant with unequal total mass

Tags: optimal-transport

I'm interested in a variant of the transportation problem and cannot find a reference for the problem I'm thinking of.

In the original Monge-Kantorovich problem about continuous transport, the total mass of $m$ objects are to be moved to the same mass of destinations. Assuming a quadratic euclidean distance cost, the solution is well known and has some nice properties.

What happens if the total masses of each side are different? e.g., if mass $1$ objects should be moved to total mass of $x$ destinations, $x\neq 1$? So if $x<1$ some of the objects cannot be moved because of this capacity constraint. On the other hand, if $x>1$, what would be the optimal transport? (assuming quadratic costs)

Anyone familiar with this variant? I can't find a reference that deals with this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant of the optimal transport problem is called "optimal partial transport".

See [here](http://www.calcvar.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1583/optimal_partial_transport.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/papers/annals2010.pdf).

Comment: Thanks so much!